# .htaccess rewerite creating pseudo subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite, using .HTACCESS, a PHP file from:

```
website.com/social.php
```

to

```
website.com/dash/social
```

how may this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dash/social /social.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^dash/social/ social.php [NC]
```

Comment: Do you have .htaccess permission on server for mod_rewrite?
Is mod_rewrite enabled on the server?

Comment: Yes, I do have permission. I am on HostGator.

Comment: Nevermind, sir. I simply had file naming issues. Everything is resolved and working like a charm. Thank you!